# How would you calculate the speed of a rotating disk with an object that enters and leaves the disk?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

[image]

How would I find the speed of a moving object that enters a rotating circle and then leaves it again?

The object moves at *s* and the distance between entering and leaving is calculable. The object does not come near the center of the circle and the object does not follow a straight line into the circle.

Comment: What are we looking at here?

Comment: @jay72 you are looking at an eddy, a rotating mass of water

Comment: So definitely not a rigid body type of problem. I would edit the title and change the tags to show that. Something like what is a particle velocity when entering and then exiting an eddy current.

Answer (score 1):

The angular momentum of the system is conserved. You can use that to calculate the change in angular momentum of the disk, provided you know the momentum of the object as it enters and leaves the disk.

Assuming that the incoming and outgoing objects are very much less massive than the disk, the centre of the disk can be used as a fixed reference point. The angular momenta of the incoming and outgoing objects, and of the disk before and after the collision, can be calculated about this point. The angular momentum of the object is its linear momentum times its perpendicular distance from the reference point. Total angular momentum before equals total angular momentum after.

The object does not necessarily have the same mass on entering as it had on leaving. It could pick up or lose mass from the disk. The path of the object in the disk is irrelevant. Only its initial and final linear momentum and distance from the centre are relevant.